# python2 vs python3 translate method

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, python-3.6

I tried to convert below python2 code to python3 but my ideas won't work. Any suggestions please?

```
    with open("somefile.b64") as f:
encryptedt = f.read().translate(None, '\n')
```

python3 code

```
with open("somefile.b64") as f:
        eStr = f.read()
        trantab = eStr.maketrans('', '\n') #Tried None as first argument
        encryptedt = eStr.translate(trantab)
```

With None as first argument, I received an error that the first argument must be a string and with empty string I received the first two maketrans arguments must have equal length

Comment: You don't even need these methods here, just `f.read().replace('\n', '')`

Comment: Read the [`str.maketrans()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans) a little more closely. You want the three argument form. (Or just [`str.replace()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace).)

Comment: Thanks very much, replace method worked well for me.

Comment: @Chris_Rands you should post this as an answer, so other people can find it quickly when searching